# powering multiple LED panels

Tags: led, transformer, lighting

I have four [50W AC 220V LED panels](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000945543270.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4cae57eaqusWNe&algo_pvid=3e998f5d-0884-4045-9de8-330044a808e5&algo_expid=3e998f5d-0884-4045-9de8-330044a808e5-4&btsid=0bb0622c16023387734701491eb134&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) I'd like to rig to light a work area. I bought a 200W [step up / down transformer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000MWAKVU) to test with and it powers a single panel fine.

I have two questions-- first, will this transformer work to power four panels? and second, is there a better way to do this (the transformer is really bulky and isn't quite what I'd want to run the circuit on-- it seems like there's got to be a more realistic and "permanent" way to power these). Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to run them in series? They are supposed to run in parallel. A 220V 200W transformer will be running at full power driving them all. SHOULD be fine if it's a good one. (If).

Comment: @BrianDrummond I didn't know that. I'll edit the question

Comment: The more compact solution would be to buy mains lighting modules which run on your actual mains voltage, and not someone else's.  This is really an off-topic product usage question; without actual engineering specifications of the items the answer could only be guessed at.  In terms of advice, overall this project sounds a bit dubious, you should probably get the right lighting modules.

Comment: I would not guarantee it can run 4 panels at once, I know 50Wx4 is 200W and it should match, but since it is so perfectly fit... cable losses and other things are enough to throw it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to power multiple things you generally put those things in parallel.If you put them in series there will be voltage drop in each element .This will result in some things are completely on , some are semi-on and some are completely off.

In your case you connect the phase in one end , the neutral in the other end and in between you put those things you want to power in parallel.